# Qt: transforming touch to mouse inside eventfilter on complex widgets

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a way of creating `QWidgets` that respond to touch, running as a plugin to a proprietary Qt 5.2 application. The application provides touch and gesture events (`QTouchEvent`, `QGestureEvent`), but no mouse events.

I have no control over the application itself, apart from what can be done at runtime, and I'm trying to be as minimally invasive as I can.

EDIT: To clarify the above paragraph, my code is being loaded automatically by Qt as a 'fake' image plugin. The host application appears to not have set `Qt::AA_SynthesizeMouseForUnhandledTouchEvents`, and when I tried to do it... things did not go well. The application has it's own set of touch and gesture handlers and Widgets it uses.

One option is to subclass each `QWidget` type and add custom event handling for touch events. I would rather not do this, however, as it would be tedious, and I don't really need advanced touch/gesture functionality for the most part.

Another option, which I've been trialing is to install an eventFilter on the widgets, which creates mouse events from the touch events, and sends the mouse event to the widget instead. This is working quite well for many simpler widgets, and even complex widgets like `QFileDialog` mostly work.

My problem comes with certain widget types (I've come across two so far), which either partially work, or don't work at all, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

An example of a partially working widget with the eventFilter technique is the `QComboBox`. The combo box itself responds to the touch, and opens the dropdown list. However, the dropdown list itself just doesn't seem to work with the touch.

`QDialogButtonBox` is the most recent widget I've discovered that doesn't work. The eventFilter seems to trigger on the `QDialogButtonBox` itself, but not the button(s) for some reason.

Here are the relevant bits of the current (very) WIP experimental code:

From `NDBWidgets.h`

```
void setTouchFilter(QWidget *w);

class TouchFilter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        TouchFilter(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    protected:
        bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override;
};
```

And from `NDBWidgets.cc`

```
static void installTouchFilter(QWidget *w)
{
    if (!w->property(touchFilterSet).isValid()) {
        w->setProperty(touchFilterSet, QVariant(true));
        w->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
        auto ef = new TouchFilter(w);
        w->installEventFilter(ef);
    }
}

void setTouchFilter(QWidget *w)
{
    if (!w) {
        return;
    }
    auto children = w->children();
    nh_log("installing eventFilter on the following children:");
    for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); ++i) {
        if (auto wi = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(children.at(i))) {
            nh_log("    Class: %s  Name: %s", children.at(i)->metaObject()->className(), children.at(i)->objectName().toUtf8().constData());
            installTouchFilter(wi);
            // if (auto cb = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(wi)) {
            //     setTouchFilter(cb->view());
            // }
        }
    }
    installTouchFilter(w);
}

TouchFilter::TouchFilter(QWidget *parent) : QObject(parent) {}

bool TouchFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) 
{
    // Only care about widgets...
    auto widget = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(obj);
    if (!widget) {
        return false;
    }
    auto type = event->type();
    if (type == QEvent::TouchBegin || type == QEvent::TouchUpdate || type == QEvent::TouchEnd) {
        event->accept();
        auto tp = static_cast<QTouchEvent*>(event)->touchPoints().at(0);
        nh_log("eventFilter triggered for class: %s name: %s", widget->metaObject()->className(), widget->objectName().toUtf8().constData());
        if (type == QEvent::TouchBegin) {
            nh_log("event TouchBegin captured");
            QMouseEvent md(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, tp.pos(), tp.screenPos(), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
            QCoreApplication::sendEvent(widget, &md);
        } else if (type == QEvent::TouchUpdate) {
            nh_log("event TouchUpdate captured");
            QMouseEvent mm(QEvent::MouseMove, tp.pos(), tp.screenPos(), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
            QCoreApplication::sendEvent(widget, &mm);
        } else if (type == QEvent::TouchEnd) {
            nh_log("event TouchEnd captured");
            QMouseEvent mu(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, tp.pos(), tp.screenPos(), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
            QCoreApplication::sendEvent(widget, &mu);
        }
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

**An example usage:**

```
void NDBDbus::dlgComboBox() {
    NDB_DBUS_USB_ASSERT((void) 0);
    auto d = new QDialog();
    d->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    auto vl = new QVBoxLayout();
    auto cb = new QComboBox(d);
    cb->addItem("Item 1", QVariant(1));
    cb->addItem("Item 2", QVariant(2));
    vl->addWidget(cb);
    auto bb = new QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Close, d);
    connect(bb, &QDialogButtonBox::rejected, d, &QDialog::reject);
    vl->addWidget(bb);
    d->setLayout(vl);
    setTouchFilter(d);
    d->open();
}
```

I'm still very new to Qt event handling, and eventFilters, and I've gotten to the point where I'm rather stumped, so if anyone has any suggestions or ideas, I would very much appreciate them!

So, TLDR, and the final question: Is it possible to transform touch events to mouse events inside an eventFilter for widgets such as `QComboBox` or `QDialogButtonBox`? And if so, how?

Comment: Do you need touch events? Why do you not let [Qt handle the translation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchevent.html#details) from touch to mouse events? Wy do you set [`Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) if you do not want touch events? Have you disabled [`Qt::AA_SynthesizeMouseForUnhandledTouchEvents`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum) unintentionally?

Comment: Because my code is a plugin for a proprietary binary. In fact, the plugin is a fake image plugin that Qt automatically loads. I'm very wary of unintended consequences of setting `Qt::AA_SynthesizeMouseForUnhandledTouchEvents`. The host application appears to have not set this, and I actually tried to set this myself... and the program started behaving weirdly. On the `Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents`, yeah, that's probably not required when using eventFilter. Was using it with my subclass experiments.

Comment: I would suggest to file a bug report for the proprietary application. As that application has special touch and gesture handlers, I would expect the application to handle all touch events correctly. All other solutions seem to be error prone and risk to be broken with every update of the original application. F.ex. how will you prevent a touch event from being processed twice by the proprietary application: once as a touch event and once as a click event that you generated?